# Not getting the 'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis' in the dictionary of the 'statistics' key , in the response of boto3 athena function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

Not getting response according to the documentation when using get_query_execution() boto3 athena  function to get 'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis'. Is there some change in the response syntax because in the docs , there  should be a key:value as  'Statistics': {'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis': 123,..}
Would be of great help if someone can tell me how to get the value of  :
**EngineExecutionTimeInMillis (integer) --The number of milliseconds that the query took to execute**.

Comment: are you using the latest boto3 version? If not upgrade to latest and try. If you are using lambda then you might be using older version of boto3 which is causing this issue

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy yes , i checked the boto3 version , it is 1.17.100 not that old i believe.

Comment: There are multiple changes made to athen boto3 compared to your version.Check release notes https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst . Latest is 1.18.55